# Pointing the pinky at v'zos hatorah

Tags: minhag, torah-service, hagbah-gelilah

By *v'zos hatorah* (i.e *hagbah*) I have seen people point their pinky at the *sefer torah*.

1. Is this a *minhag* or did someone just make it up? Where did this *minhag* come from?
2. Does the *Shulchan Aruch, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* or *Mishnah Berurah* talk about it?
3. What should an *Ashkenazi, Sefardi,* or *Yeki* do?